# How to execute requests sequentially running multiple JMeter Threads

Tags: jmeter

I have a single thread group which has 3 requests and have set the Number of Threads(users) = 2.

I would like all the requests to be executed in sequential order for each user before it repeats these steps for the next user and so on.

Output expected:
   HTTP Request 1_Thread 1
   HTTP Request 2_Thread 1
   HTTP Request 3_Thread 1
   HTTP Request 1_Thread 2
   HTTP Request 2_Thread 2
   HTTP Request 3_Thread 2

However, the output results vary differently for each run and are not in the order I expect. How can this be corrected?
I have tried following but with no luck in achieving my output
1. Enable/disable "Run Thread Groups consecutively
2. Running the test in non-GUI mode

I have attached a screenshot as an image as I am not able to embed into this message yet.

Appreciate if anyone can help me with this query

Thanks
Output Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For execution of Sampler Request by only Single Thread at a time use Critical Section Controller. 
For more info about Critical Section Controller [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)

The Critical Section Controller ensures that its children elements (samplers/controllers, etc.) will be executed by only one thread as a named lock will be taken before executing children of controller.

> Critical Section Controller takes locks only within one JVM, so if using Distributed testing ensure your use case does not rely on all threads of all JVMs blocking.

Practical Example:

1. Place all your request under **Critical Section Controller**
2. Run the test for any number of Threads you want
3. Observe the Result in View Results Tree

**Note : If you want to run it sequentially from 1 thread to N, make sure you provide Ramp Up Period properly.**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this feature which i was not aware (just started Jmeter a few days ago).... This has worked as you have mentioned.. I will keep this in mind while running in distributed mod as per your suggestion.  Thanks a ton !! :)

Comment: How to concurrently execute those request per users? I tried this but its like dont proceed to execute other users in my csv config